# Error in automatic conversion

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

```
class Sample
{
public:
  Sample();
  Sample(int i);
  Sample(Sample& s);
  ~Sample();
};

Sample::Sample()
{
  cout<<"Default constructor called\n";
}

Sample::Sample(int i)
{
  cout<<"1-argument constructor called\n";
}

Sample::Sample(Sample& s)
{
  cout<<"Copy constructor called\n";
}

Sample::~Sample()
{
  cout<<"Destructor called\n";
}

void Fun(Sample s)
{

}

int main()
{
  Sample s1;
  Fun(5);

  return 0;
}
```

I expected an implicit conversion of 5. 
But, When I compile the above code, I get following error:

```
main.cpp:7:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘Sample::Sample(Sample)’
main.cpp:7:8: note: candidates are:
Sample.h:10:3: note: Sample::Sample(Sample&)
Sample.h:10:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Sample’ to ‘Sample&’
Sample.h:9:3: note: Sample::Sample(int)
Sample.h:9:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Sample’ to ‘int’
Sample.h:8:3: note: Sample::Sample()
Sample.h:8:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
Helper.h:6:13: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void Fun(Sample)’
```

What is the problem? When i remove the copy constructor, the above code compiles successfully.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why does "Fun(5);" invokes "Sample::Sample(int i)"  ? how the converting work in such case  ?

Comment: @URL87 There is a single argument constructor that should be called if it is not marked explicit. But what role copy constructor playing here and not letting the code compile, that is my confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Temporaries cannot bind to non-const references. Your copy constructor should be:

```
Sample::Sample(const Sample&)
```

Removing it tells the compiler to generate a trivial one, which will have the above signature.

Comment: If i remove copy constructor, it calls 1 arg constructor for implicit conversion from int 5 to Sample object using 1-arg constructor. But when i add the above copy constructor, it starts reporting error. Why it starts confusing with copy constructor when its conversion can simply be done using 1-arg constructor just like before adding the above copy constructor.

Comment: @abhithakur88 that means you have to give more context - how you're calling the function, etc.

Comment: I am calling the function Fun from main, please use srollbar in above code and see there is a main function as well..

Comment: @abhithakur88 the call creates a temporary `Sample` using `Sample(int)` and then attempts to copy that temporary using the copy cosntructor because you pass the argument by value. Please re-read the answer. I don't see how I haven't already explained this...

Comment: Thanks Luchian, you are my hero :-)